# App Can't be installed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, terminal

I'm trying to test installing my app and am having some issues. I built a .pkg using terminals productbuild command. Then I tried testing the installation using sudo installer on the .pkg I made with product build. When I try to run the sudo installer I get a message in terminal stating "theApp can't be installed on this computer". Any ideas why this could happen?

EDIT: Figured it out. Turns out there is a special installer command for running app store packages. For anyone who needs it the command is

```
    sudo installer -store -pkg /Users/MyApp/ -target /DirectoryToInstallTo
```

Comment: You should be able to just double click your .pkg file to install. What version of OSX did you target for your build and what version are you running?

Comment: My project Base SDK is set to 10.7 and my computer is running 10.7.

I was just looking at PackageMaker. Can I use that to make a .pkg to submit to the Mac App Store?

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention anything about Mac Store originally. Have you read http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/DistApps/DistApps.html?

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for. Do you happen to know if the .pkg's compiled for the App Store should run like a normal .pkg? What I mean is, when I double click on a .pkg that I built to submit to the App Store, should the .pkg install my app?